# getting resized product pictures without loading product

Tags: php, magento

Regarding the poor performances of my magento homepage (4 seconds computing before it start loading assets) i optimized my source code to go down to 1 second, by removing all the $_product->load that were in my loops.

But i'm facing another issue, i can't call the picture this way anoymore :

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(135); ?>"
```

so, i began to call thumbnails

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>
```

but there's few points that annoys me, the 2nd call don't get a default placeholder picture if no picture is found, and the bigger problem is, all the magento's product have only a large res file, which is called if i don't upload a thumbnail for each product (note : i got 1600+ products, i'd like to avoid a manual upload for every single item)

So i have two options : getting th catalog/image helper to work without loading product, or finding a way to generate all the thumbnail with the high res pictures (i looked for an extension doing this, but i guess i'm a bad googler)

EDIT : here's the collection call

```
$selections_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect(
    array(
      'name',
      'special_from_date',
      'special_to_date',
      'thumbnail',
      'image',
      'couleur',
      'special_price',
      'url_path',
      'price',
      'format',
      'selection_moment',
      'selection_rouge',
      'selection_blanc',
      'selection_cdc',
      'selection_champagne',
      'selection_exception'
    )
)
->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'attribute_set_id', 'like' => '4')))
->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=>'selection_moment', 'like' => '1'),
        array('attribute'=>'selection_rouge', 'like' => '1'),
        array('attribute'=>'selection_blanc', 'like' => '1'),
        array('attribute'=>'selection_cdc', 'like' => '1'),
        array('attribute'=>'selection_champagne', 'like' => '1'),
        array('attribute'=>'selection_exception', 'like' => '1')
    )
);
$selections_products->getSelect()->limit(32);
```

EDIT 2 : foreach on the collection :

```
<?php $i = 0;
    foreach($selections_products_rouge as $_product): ?>
<?php if($i==0 || $i==4): ?>
<tr>
<?php endif; ?>
    <td>
        <div class="prod-resume">
            <div class="thumb-wrapper">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <div class="pic-holder">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                            <img height="220" src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h3 class="title"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></h3>
            <div class="type">
            <?php 
            $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
            $j = 0;
            foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
                $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
                if($_cat->getLevel() != 2 && $j < 2 && $_cat->getName() != 'Default Category'){
                    echo '<span>'.$_cat->getName().'</span>';
                    $j++;
                }
            }
            $couleur = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('couleur')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
            $format = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('format')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
            echo '<span>'.$couleur.'</span>';
            echo '<span>'.$format.'</span>';
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo get_promo_stamp($_product); ?>
            <div class="bottom">
                <?php echo get_product_price_html($_product,$_taxHelper,$_coreHelper); ?>
                <div class="btns">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="prod">Fiche produit</a>
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="basket">Ajouter au panier</a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="preview btn-popin">Aperçu</a>
        </div>
    </td>
<?php if($i==3 || $i==7): ?>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $i++;endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: question lacks with your code. Please provide product collection code here.

Comment: Sorry, i just added the collection call

Comment: on `init()` method, you specified `$_product`, in your edit code I can't see definition for `$_product`. What it holds ?

Comment: Oh sorry you cannot use that method due to the new code. Is that right ?

Comment: i added the foreach loop as well, you can see that $_product are direct iterations of the collection items. I still get a $_product, but i can't get the picture resizer to work without loading the product inside the foreach with $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());

Comment: Are you using flat tables feature in magento?